# C# WPF Change datagrid cell background after CellEditEnding event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, background-color

I have a **Datagrid** (DataGridMeterValues) in my C# wpf application. Everytime the user exits the editing mode of a cell, the **CellEditEnding** event is triggered.

Now I wish to change the background of the cell when the event is triggered.

This is what I got so far:

```
private void DataGridMeterValues_CellEditEnding(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{

// Code to change background color here

}
```

I am able to change the background of a full row with following code:

```
e.Row.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Now my question is, can I do the same but then only for 1 cell (the selected one) not the entire row

**EDIT:** This is the XAML for the datagrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="DataGridMeterValues" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MeterValuesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" FrozenColumnCount="0" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Margin="2,0" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="All" AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" IsEnabled="True" CellEditEnding="DataGridMeterValues_CellEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="DataGridBase" TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
                </Style >
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>                  
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle >
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="X" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Button Tag="{Binding}" Content="Activate" Width="50" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2" Background="{Binding Path=Activated}" Click="BtnActivate_Click" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meter Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void DataGridMeterValues_CellEditEnding(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{

        FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(DataGridMeterValues.SelectedItem);
        (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

}
```

I have fetched the framework element of the cell in selected row and column. Then I got DataGridCell from that element using its Parent property and set its background property. :)

There can be multiple templates inside a DataGridCell. Its better we fetched the DataGridCell and used its background property.

Comment: How would u do it with `SelectionUnit="Cell"` ?

Comment: Oh I just did `FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);` and works okay :)